# Gatsby App -> AWS Lambda to Google Auth back to Gatsby

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, gatsby, google-authentication

I have a click action the sends a fetch request to a AWS Lambda function that runs a google auth script, that then returns a url to authorize with back to the fetch request and with `window.location` sends me to google to authorize, I authorize and currently I have it send me back to the same lambda. I can't just sent it back to the Gatsby site, because google needs a the auth redirect url to return a 200 status code and I couldn't just create a page on my site like /auth for the redirect. So once Im redirected to the original lambda, the authorization code is appended to the url. So so far that works just fine.

What I am stuck on is the next step.

A) How do I redirect the user back to the Gatsby site?

B) do I store that auth (pull it from the url params) in a database somewhere I could use faundDB Im familiar with that and lambda functions.

C) And should I be sending google to a separate lambda then the one I send the fetch request to, will it really matter.

I am using a NodeJS Lambda

Here is my lambda

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
// const axios = require('axios')
// const url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';
let response;

/**
 *
 * Event doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format
 * @param {Object} event - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Input Format
 *
 * Context doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html
 * @param {Object} context
 *
 * Return doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
 * @returns {Object} object - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Output Format
 *
 */
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      "1fdsfas",
      "uiPCvLfsdfs",
      "https://fdsfa/test"
    );

    // generate a url that asks permissions for Blogger and Google Calendar scopes
    const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"];

    const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
      access_type: "offline",

      // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
      scope: scopes,
    });

    console.log(url);

    // const ret = await axios(url);
    response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: "Hello World",
        urlAuth: url,
        // location: ret.data.trim()
      }),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }

  return response;
};
```

Here is my fetch request

```
const click = () => {
    fetch("http://fdsaf/test")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.urlAuth)
        window.location.href = response.urlAuth
      })
  }
```

Comment: it looks like I am supposed to grab the code and convert it to a refresh token and store that in my database. I guess I will do that. But for the redirect I am not sure how to do that. Will doing a 302 redirect mean the url will never get the params added?

Comment: I first need to decide if this should be done in a sepearate lambda, I think for clarity it would make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I ended up creating a second lambda to push to the database as the call bakc url for the google auth. and then 301 redirect to localhost for now.

```
// const axios = require('axios')
// const url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';
let response;
const faunadb = require("faunadb"); /* Import faunaDB sdk */

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    // const ret = await axios(url);
    let code;
    if (event.queryStringParameters) {
      code = event.queryStringParameters.code;
    } else {
      code = "no code";
    }

    // Connect to the database
    const q = faunadb.query;
    const client = new faunadb.Client({
      secret: "fdsafa",
    });


    //This line gets u your refresh token from the code as a object
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);

    await client
      .query(q.Create(q.Collection("AuthUrl"), { data: { title: tokens } }))
      .then((ret) => console.log(ret));


    response = {
      statusCode: 301,
      headers: {
        Location: "http://localhost:8000",
      },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
  }

  return response;
};
```